# Is the kernel of a group homomorphism unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I just began learning group theory and this question came across my mind.

Suppose $f :G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, where $G$ and $H$ are groups. Is $\ker f $ unique?

Based on my understanding, since homomorphism preserves identity from $G$ to $H$, and that identity in groups $G$ and $H$ is unique, there is only a unique element in $\ker f $.

Comment: Why wouldn't the kernel be unique, exactly? It's a predefined set, and - given $f$ and $G$ - $\ker(f)$ can only be precisely one set. But this also doesn't mean that the kernel is solely the identity element, however, as your later bits in the OP seem to suggest. Simply consider the homomorphism

$$f : (\mathbb{Z},+) \to (\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}, \oplus) \text{ where } f(x) = [x]_n$$

(i.e. we send each element to its equivalence class in mod $n$ arithmetic). Notice how

$$\ker(f) = 6 \mathbb{Z} \supsetneq \{0\}$$

Comment: homomorphisms _preserve_ the identity, but need not _reflect_ it. That is, it's true that $f(1_G) = y$ implies $y=1_H$. But it's _not_ true that $f(x) = 1_H$ implies $x=1_G$.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. What I am actually trying to ask if whether is there only a unique element in ker F

Comment: As noted, the answer to that question is "no". (And the notion of a kernel would be pretty pointless if it always just contained the identity.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument only shows that the identity element of $G$ is contained in the kernel of $f$. There might be more elements depending on $f$ though.

To give an extreme example:
Let $G$ and $H$ be arbitrary groups and consider the homomorphism $1 \colon G \rightarrow H$ of groups that sends each element of $G$ to the identity element of $H$. Then the kernel of $1$ coincides with the group $G$.

Comment: Wouldn't this contradict the fact that homomorphism preserves identity? In this case every element of G will be an identity, then the identity of G will not be unqiue.

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with the uniqueness of the identity. $G$ is a group and thus has a unique identity element. An element is not an identity element just because it is mapped to an identity element under a group homomorphism. That is what we are all trying to tell you. Just make the situation as concrete as you can. Pick your favorite group (e.g. $G = \mathbb{Z}$ with the normal addition of integers) and now pick some group $H$ (you can also just pick ($H = \mathbb{Z}$ again if you want to). Try to check that in this case the map that send every lets say integer as in the example

Comment: to $0$ is a group homomorphism. But that does not mean that any other element than $0$ is an identity element.

Comment: Depends on how you interpret "preserves".  The image of the identity under a homomorphism is the identity.  But, elements apart from identity can be mapped to identity.

Comment: Yep understood now, the misunderstanding here is I thought homomorphisms sends the identity from G to H and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Con and Divakaran

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @lel: Now that you've clarified this aspect of how homomorphisms work, you might want to look at the special case of isomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

By definition$$\ker f=\{g\in G\mid f(g)=e_H\}.\tag1$$So, if you are asking whether $\ker f$ is a unique set, the answer is affirmative, since $\ker f$ is defined by $(1)$; it's a single set. But it seems to me that the question is in fact about whether $\ker f$ consists only of $e_G$. In general, no. If $G$ has more than one element and if $(\forall g\in G):f(g)=e_H$, then $\ker f=G\ne\{e_g\}$.

Comment: Why $ ker F $ does not consists only of $ e_G $? Is there an example for this under the context of my question?

Comment: I have just provided infinitely many examples. Take *any group* $G$ *with more than one element*, let $H$ be any group and define $f(g)=e_H$. Then $\ker f=\{G\}\ne\{e_G\}$. What more do you want?

Comment: Sorry for the extra clarification. I understand fully now. It is because i neglected the fact that although homomorphisms sends the identity in G to H, the reverse isn't so, since the homomorphism is not necessarily injective. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I suggest that you mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Kernel of a homomorphism $f:G \to H$ is a set and the set is uniquely defined.  If $0$ is the identity in $H$, then the $\ker(f) = \{g\in G \ | \ f(g) = 0\}$.  However, the kernel need not have a unique element.  Look at the following example:

Let $G$ be the group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition.  Consider the set $\{0,1\}$  and check that the set along with the operation defined as $0+0 = 0 = 1 + 1$ and $0+1 = 1 = 1+0$ forms a group.  Call this group $H$.  Further check that the operation $f: G \to H$ defined as $f(z) = 0$ if $z$ is even and $f(z) = 1$ if $z$ is odd is a homomorphism.  Finally check that the kernel of $f$ is the set of even integers.